# Tangent Circles At Triangle Vertices

Tags: python, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm struggling to convert the formula from this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentCircles.html) and translate it into Python, or any code for that matter, mainly because I find it hard to read math equations. Ideally, given the positions of **A**, **B** and **C**, find out the radii *a'*, *b'* and *c'* for the image on the left. Any help would be really apprciated.

[image: Tangent Circles At Triangle Vertices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the vertex coordinates are `(xa, ya)` for point `A`, `(xb, yb)` for point `B`, and `(xc, yc)` for point `C`, you could use

```
a = math.sqrt((xb - xc)**2 + (yb - yc)**2)
b = math.sqrt((xa - xc)**2 + (ya - yc)**2)
c = math.sqrt((xb - xa)**2 + (yb - ya)**2)
ra = (b + c - a) / 2
rb = (c + a - b) / 2
rc = (a + b - c) / 2
```

and the desired radii are in `ra, rb, rc`. (I don't know how to translate `a'` etc. into Python so I used `ra` etc.) Values `a, b, c` are the lengths of the sides of the triangle. Note that I changed the formulas slightly from your linked article, to make them more symmetrical and pleasing to my eye.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Would it be easy to apply this to three dimensions? So `xa, ya, za` for point `A`, `xb, yb, zb` for point `B` and `xc, yc, zc` for point `C`?

Comment: If you mean to find the radii of the three tangent circles *in the plane of the three points*, yes, you could easily apply that to three dimensions. Just adjust the formulas for `a, b, c` to find the triangle's sides in 3-space: `a = math.sqrt((xb - xc)**2 + (yb - yc)**2 + (zb - zc)**2)`. You do not need to adjust the formulas for the radii `ra` etc..